# Comparar varias columnas de Excel

Tags: excel, vba

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De la siguiente imagen anterior quiero crear un macro que haga lo siguiente:

Lo que quiero es hacer un ciclo que recorra las filas de mis datos:
comparar fila1 de la columna A con fila1 de la columna G y comparar fila1 de la columna B con fila1 de la columna I si este es true almacena en una variable el valor de la fila1 de la columna H

y avance a la siguiente fila en las columnas G, H, I. 
Ahora hace la misma comparación fila1 A con fila 2 G y fila 1 B con fila2 I y si es true suma el valor de la columna H anterior con la actual y así sucesivamente.

Es decir

- -8403 = -8403 AND 1 = 1 Entonces var = 9
- -8403 = -8403 AND 1 = 1 Entonces var = 9 + 11

Tengo el siguiente código que compara las existencias de la columna A en la columna G y me funciona a la perfección pero ahora quiero comparar mas columnas.

```
Sub ObtenerCoincidencias()
    Dim ClaveCat As Range
    Dim ClaveExi As Range

    Dim x As Object
    Dim y As Object


    Set ClaveExi = Range("A2:A18")
    Set ClaveCat = Range("G2:G350")


    For Each x In ClaveExi
        For Each y In ClaveCat
            If x = y Then
            y.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 204, 0)
            End If
        Next y
    Next x
End Sub
```

Alguna sugerencia para mejorar mi código y logre realizar la tarea que requiero, de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haber entendido bien.

Hice el recorrido de una manera diferente con la finalidad de que tus rangos de datos no sean fijos.

Con el extracto de datos de la imagen que adjunto el resultado de la variable (var) que va incrementando dio 20.

Aquí el código:

```
Sub ObtenerCoincidencias()

Dim ultimaFilaIzq As Integer
Dim ultimaFilaDer As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim d As Integer
Dim var As Integer

var = 0
ultimaFilaIzq = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ultimaFilaDer = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To ultimaFilaIzq

    For d = 1 To ultimaFilaDer

        If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("G" & d).Value And Range("B" & i).Value = Range("I" & d).Value Then
            var = var + Range("H" & d).Value
        End If

    Next d

Next i
MsgBox var
```

End Sub

Comment: Perfecto, con algunas modificaciones me funciona! muchas Gracias.

Comment: Para servirte. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Hay otra solucion menos complicada que VBA y se utiliza todo el poder de Excel y Bases de Datos Relacionales.

1. Convierte cada tabla como datos como **Formato como Tabla**.
2. Crea un campo **id** concatenando `[CLAVE]&[NUM ALMACEN]` en cada tabla.
3. Crea una relación entre las tablas usando `[id]` como llave en común de las dos tablas.
4. Inserta una tabla dinámica y juega con su data :D

[image]

[image]

Comment: Es cierto es una manera diferente de resolver la problemática, muchas gracias.